# Bash iterate through multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, bash, loops

I have defined multiple arrays:

```
array1=(el1 el2 el3 el4 el5)
array2=(el10 el12 el14)
array3=(el5 el4 el11 el8)
```

I need to iterate through all elements of all arrays. The following is the syntax I use:

```
for j in {1..3}
do
    for (( k = 0 ; k < ${#array$j[*]} ; k++ ))
    do
        #perform actions on array elements, refer to array elements as "${array$j[$k]}"
    done
done
```

However, the above snippet fails with the message(s)

```
k < ${#array$j[*]} : bad substitution and 
${array$j[$k]}: bad substitution
```

What is wrong with my array syntax?

Comment: Do you really need `$j` and `$k`, or can you just write `for value in "${array1[@]}" "${array2[@]}" "${array3[@]}" ; do ... ; done`?

Comment: unfortunately, I do. Actual number of arrays is 11, and actions on elements within each array need to be distinct.

Comment: Your syntax for array assignment is wrong, there shouldn't be any commas.

Comment: Apologies - that was just a typo I made when writing the question. Array specification in my script doesn't have any commas.

Answer (score 1):

Your script is not correct.

1. First of all there should not be comma separating various elements in your 3 arrays.
2. Then to use array name as variable you need to use indirection

Following should work:

```
array1=(el1 el2 el3 el4 el5)
array2=(el10 el12 el14)
array3=(el5 el4 el11 el8)

for j in {1..3}
do
    n="array$j[@]"
    arr=("${!n}")
    for (( k = 0 ; k < ${#arr[@]} ; k++ ))
    do
        #perform actions on array elements, refer to array elements as "${array$j[$k]}"
        echo "Processing: ${arr[$k]}"
    done
done
```

This will process all 3 arrays and gives this output:

```
Processing: el1
Processing: el2
Processing: el3
Processing: el4
Processing: el5
Processing: el10
Processing: el12
Processing: el14
Processing: el5
Processing: el4
Processing: el11
Processing: el8
```

Comment: Ha, we just posted the same answer within fifteen seconds of each other. Great minds . . . ! :-P

Comment: Wow that was really funny, cant agree more :)

Comment: Thank you - that did it.  Commas in the array definition was just a typo I made when writing the question. Array specification in my script doesn't have any commas. Use of indirection solved the problem.

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
array1=(el1 el2 el3 el4 el5)
array2=(el10 el12 el14)
array3=(el5 el4 el11 el8)

for j in {1..3} ; do
    # copy array$j to a new array called tmp_array:
    tmp_array_name="array$j[@]"
    tmp_array=("${!tmp_array_name}")

    # iterate over the keys of tmp_array:
    for k in "${!tmp_array[@]}" ; do
        echo "\${array$j[$k]} is ${tmp_array[k]}"
    done
done
```

prints this:

```
${array1[0]} is el1
${array1[1]} is el2
${array1[2]} is el3
${array1[3]} is el4
${array1[4]} is el5
${array2[0]} is el10
${array2[1]} is el12
${array2[2]} is el14
${array3[0]} is el5
${array3[1]} is el4
${array3[2]} is el11
${array3[3]} is el8
```

There may well be some way to do this without creating `tmp_array`, but I couldn't get the indirection to work without it.